# iphone app sporadically hangs for a few seconds

Tags: iphone, performance

When I run my Iphone app on my Ipod touch, it runs fine most of the time.  But every so often, it will hang for a short while -- anywhere from 5 to 15 seconds.  After the hang, it resumes running normally.

The strange thing is that to all appearances, the app's demands on the system should be fairly steady.  It is doing a lot of dragging stuff around with calls to TouchesMoved.  But it drags a maximum of two labels at a time.

How might I go about tracking down such a problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good start would be to run your app under Shark to see where it is spending most time during those periods.

Comment: I've been trying!  But this brings me to problem #2 . . . Shark says debug symbols are not available.  But the "generate debug symbols" box under compiler options is checked!  So I have no idea what is causing this either . . .

Comment: Make sure Debug Information Format is set to DWARF with dSYM file.